# Changing TextField style dynamically in Extjs

Tags: dynamic, extjs, passwords, textfield, background-color

I'm trying to set the background-color and color of a TextField (to mask a password) on a checkbox click event. My best try:

```
var hidePass = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            boxLabel: 'Hide Password',
            name: 'hidePass',
            handler: function (checkbox, checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    pass1.fieldStyle = 'background-color: #ddd; background-image: none;';
                }
            }
        });
```

this code doesn't work. No errors are thrown. I'm not sure where to go from here. I've searched everywhere and can't find anything like this. I can't find any properties or methods to change the style that works.

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck using 3.3

Comment: I've come up with a workaround solution. I just add a class to the password field in the handler if it's checked and then use an inline stylesheet. Not very elegant though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First make sure to have an id for you item
2.Now try `Ext.get('yourID').setStyle('margin-top','30px');`
--This should work

Comment: I'm hoping this is right, as I'm long past being able to test this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ExtJs 4, don't assign style like this directly. Use `setStyle` method: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-setFieldStyle